# Why do my raytraced spheres have dark lines when lit with multiple light sources?

Tags: objective-c, raytracing

I have a simple raytracer that only works back up to the first intersection.  The scene looks OK with two different light sources, but when both lights are in the scene, there are dark shadows where the lit area from one ends, even if in the middle of a lit area from the other light source (particularly noticeable on the green ball).  The transition from the 'area lit by both light sources' to the 'area lit by just one light source' seems to be slightly darker than the 'area lit by just one light source'.

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

The code where I'm adding the lighting effects is:

```
// trace lights
        for ( int l=0; l<primitives.count; l++) {

            Primitive* p = [primitives objectAtIndex:l];
            if (p.light) 
            {
                Sphere * lightSource = (Sphere *)p;

                // calculate diffuse shading
                Vector3 *light = [[Vector3 alloc] init];
                light.x = lightSource.centre.x - intersectionPoint.x;
                light.y = lightSource.centre.y - intersectionPoint.y;
                light.z = lightSource.centre.z - intersectionPoint.z;

                [light normalize];

                Vector3 * normal = [[primitiveThatWasHit getNormalAt:intersectionPoint] retain];
                if (primitiveThatWasHit.material.diffuse > 0)
                {
                    float illumination = DOT(normal, light);
                    if (illumination > 0)
                    {
                        float diff = illumination * primitiveThatWasHit.material.diffuse;
                        // add diffuse component to ray color
                        colour.red += diff * primitiveThatWasHit.material.colour.red * lightSource.material.colour.red;
                        colour.blue += diff * primitiveThatWasHit.material.colour.blue * lightSource.material.colour.blue;
                        colour.green += diff * primitiveThatWasHit.material.colour.green * lightSource.material.colour.green;
                    }
                }
                [normal release];
                [light release];
            }
        }
```

How can I make it look right?

Comment: Pretty sure this is just an illusion in the overlapping highlights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a perceptual effect called [Mach banding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_bands).

You are also very likely viewing the images in the wrong color space.  Your ray tracer is doing the lighting math in a "linear" space, but then you are almost certainly viewing those images on a display with a nonlinear response, and therefore not even seeing the correct results.  This could easily be making the Mach bands much more prominent than if you were displaying them properly.  Try learning about [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction).

Answer (score 3):

Your eyes are decieving you. If you move the spheres from the 3 pictures together you will very clearly see that the areas are the same color when single light and brighter when double lit. If you want to make it look nicer I suggest you add a whole arc of light sources between the current ones.

Comment: Well, yes, you're absolutely right.  I used a colour picker tool and did a comparison of the pixels I was suspicious of.  It turns out that they only look darker, they are actually the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

You've saturated one colour channel in the image; turn down the brightness a bit and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your lighting directions are *both* normalized?

May be worth it to throw an assert in there.